# Setup store view on different host

Tags: magento, magento-1.4

I have a Magento 1.4 webshop with multiple store views, every storeview is a different language. For SEO purposes, my client wanted to run the german store view on a different (german) host.

To achieve this, I've:

- cloned all the code to the second (german) server.
- modified the index.php on the german server so it starts the right store view
- setup a cronjob to sync the  /media folder every hour
- let the german store use the main database connection (shared db)

Everything seemed to work fine, but different customers report having Internal Server Errors, and sometimes there is garbled (binary) text being shown the first visit. After one or two reloads, everything works again.

I've tried some things to fix it:

- disabled gzip on both servers
- setup memcache, let the german store connect to the main store

Nothing seems to work. So I was wondering, *Is* there an official/'right' way to share one webshop over multiple hosts, using the community edition. And if there is, what could I be doing wrong?

Answer (score 1):

## Your issue ...

***How "far apart" are the two servers?***

If quite far, even with a 100Mbit/1Gbit connection, the latency will cripple your MySQL connection and it is ever likely that this latency is what is causing your odd issues. This will also impact, nigh on ruin, any benefits Memcache will provide (if you are using the remote Memcache instance). If anything, you should have a Memcache instance running on each server.

**Have you got MySQL tunnelled via SSH (Xinetd/persistent SSH tunnel etc.)?**

The security is great, but the compression will add overheads. Also bear in mind using Xinetd will add extra latency for the connection open/close.

If it isn't tunnelled - you are putting your store and your customers at risk by sending sensitive plain text data.

## The best & most simple solution

Well, my initial advice would be not to run the store on two different hosts. But instead find a host that can present you with an IP on two different subnets, presented at the same data-centre (I'm assuming your client's concern is IP geolocation). Then you can keep 1 code-base.

Failing two different IP ranges, I would just tell your client to watch this, even Google say IP address location has no bearing on SERPs.

http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=keIzr3eWK8I&noredirect=1

## The more complex solution

Running a distributed store where the servers are globally diverse is going to introduce a host of issues (namely speed) if you are using a single remote database server.

It would be advisable to ensure your database server is located at the same site as the web server that is catering for your primary market; then have a second web server in your secondary market.

Then, on your secondary web server, configure a MySQL slave instance and instruct Magento to perform all its reads locally (from the slave server) and write to the remote server. You will induce latency on writes, and slave updates will have the same - but it is the most satisfactory solution (if you insist on approaching it in a complex manner).

Using a Varnish instance in front of both web servers will help buffer any performance issues and give an all-round pleasing experience to your end users.

This is the type of deployment we would use when addressing an Enterprise Magento store that targets several global markets and insists on using a single administration store view (rather than a multitude of 'feeder' stores in to a single ERP system).

Comment: Thanks for your informative answer. I have just found a bug that seemed to have caused most of the problems. Some pages were still compressed altough gzipping was disabled in the .htaccess.

I agree that running the same shop on two different host is a bad idea, I already told my client that, but he wants it done no matter what.

The servers are within 100 miles from each other, I'm not using tunneling for Mysql. I'll consider switching to a more secure solution.

Comment: Sounds like a recipe for disaster :(